# Apache Kafka - Implementing a KTable

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

I am new to Kafka Streams API and I am trying to create a KTable. I have an input topic: `s-order-topic`, which is a json format message, as shown below.

```
{ "current_ts": "2019-12-24 13:16:40.316952",
  "primary_keys": ["ID"],
  "before": null,
  "tokens": {"txid":"3.17.2493", 
             "csn":"64913009"},
  "op_type":"I",
  "after":  { "CODE":"AAAA41",
              "STATUS":"COMPLETED",
              "ID":24},
  "op_ts":"2019-12-24 13:16:40.316941",
  "table":"S_ORDER"}
```

I read messages from this topic and I want to create a **KTable** that has as **key**, the field `"after":"ID"` and for **value** all the fields inside the `"after"` field (except for `"ID"`).

I have successfully created a KTable only when I use the default aggregate functions i.e count. But I have difficulty creating my own aggregate function. Below I present the part of the code that I try to create the KTable.

```
KTable<Long, String> s_table = builder.stream("s-order-topic",  Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(),Serdes.String()))
                .mapValues(value -> {
                    String time;
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
                    if (json.getString("op_type").equals("I")) {
                        time = "after";
                    }else {
                        time = "before";
                    }
                    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json.getJSONObject(time).toString());
                    return json2.toString();
                })
               .groupBy((key, value) -> {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
                    return json.getLong("ID");
                }, Grouped.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.String()))
                .aggregate( ... );
```

How can I implement this KTable?

Am I approaching the problem correctly?

(mapValues -> keep only the "before"/"after" field. groupBy -> Make the ID the key of the message. Aggregate -> ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution for my case. I implemented the KTable as shown below:

```
 KTable<String, String> s_table = builder.stream("s-order-topic",  Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()))
                .mapValues(value -> {
                    String time;
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
                    if (json.getString("op_type").equals("I")) {
                        time = "after";
                    }else {
                        time = "before";
                    }
                    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(json.getJSONObject(time).toString());
                    return json2.toString();
                })
                .groupBy((key, value) -> {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
                    return String.valueOf(json.getLong("ID"));
                }, Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .reduce((prev,newval)->newval);
```

The `aggregate` function is not suitable for this case, instead I used the `reduce` function.

The output from the console consumer is shown below:

```
15   {"CODE":"AAAA17","STATUS":"PENDING","ID":15}
18   {"CODE":"AAAA50","STATUS":"SUBMITTED","ID":18}
4    {"CODE":"AAAA80","STATUS":"SUBMITTED","ID":4}
19   {"CODE":"AAAA83","STATUS":"SUBMITTED","ID":19}
18   {"CODE":"AAAA33","STATUS":"COMPLETED","ID":18}
5    {"CODE":"AAAA38","STATUS":"PENDING","ID":5}
10   {"CODE":"AAAA1","STATUS":"COMPLETED","ID":10}
3    {"CODE":"AAAA68","STATUS":"NOT COMPLETED","ID":3}
9    {"CODE":"AAAA89","STATUS":"PENDING","ID":9}
```

Comment: Just a side comment: Aggregation is a generalization of `reduce()` allowing you to change the output type (for reduce, input value type == output value type). Thus, using an aggregation should actually also work.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for the correction! So my problem should have been that I am not implementing aggregate correctly for my case.